# Yii2 Dependent Drop down list not working

Tags: yii2

I have a Customer fiels that is dependent on a Project field.
In my form, I have a dropdown for project, and I need my second dropdown of customers to change dynamically according to the project.
I find the solution in a few places on the web, but the array doesn't change.
Can anyone help with this?

My form:

```
$dataProject=ArrayHelper::map(Project::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name');
  echo $form->field($model, 'project_id')->dropDownList($dataProject,
       ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Project-',
       'onchange'=>'
            $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('customer/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
            $( "select#title" ).html( data );
       });
  ']);
  $dataPost=ArrayHelper::map(Customer::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'first_name');
  echo $form->field($model, 'customer_id')
       ->dropDownList(
            $dataPost,
            ['id'=>'title']
       );
```

Code in the Customer controller:

```
public function actionLists($id) {
 $countPosts = Customer::find()
      ->where(['project_id' => $id])
      ->count();
 $posts = Customer::find()
      ->where(['project_id' => $id])
      ->orderBy('id DESC')
      ->all();
 if($countPosts>0) {
      foreach($posts as $post){
           echo "<option value='".$post->id."'>".$post->first_name."</option>";
      }
 }
 else{
      echo "<option>-</option>";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the best way to add the dropdown options to the select when you have the access to jquery is to use `.each()` but you need to provide the options from the `controller/action` as `json` rather than creating the html and then adding the html to the dropdown.

Then you are using `$.post` and adding query string with the `url` for the `id` whereas you can use the `data` option to send the `id`.

Change your `onchange` function to the following

```
'onchange'=>'
     $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/customer/lists').'", {id:$(this).val()},function( data ) {

         //this will clear the dropdown of the previous options

         $("#title").children("option").remove();

         //optionally you can use the following if you have a placeholder in the dropdown so that the first option is not removed
         //$("#title").children("option:not(:first)").remove();

         $.each(data, function(key, value) {

         $("#title")
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value",key)
             .text(value)); 
         });
});
```

Then you are querying 2 times to the `Customer` table once for count all records and one for all the lists of customers

```
$countPosts = Customer::find()
      ->where(['project_id' => $id])
      ->count();
$posts = Customer::find()
      ->where(['project_id' => $id])
      ->orderBy('id DESC')
      ->all();
```

you can simply query for the customers and use `php:count()` function on the result set `$posts` to count the total number of records.

```
  $posts = Customer::find()
          ->where(['project_id' => $id])
          ->orderBy('id DESC')
          ->all();
  $countPosts = count($post);
```

But we are not going to need the `count` anyway this was just for information, change your action `actionLists()` to below and remove the parameter `$id` now as we are sending the id with `post`.

```
public function actionLists() {
    //set the response format to JSON
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    //get the id 
    $id = Yii::$app->request->post ( 'id' );

    $posts = Customer::find ()
            ->where ( [ 'project_id' => $id ] )
            ->orderBy ( 'id DESC' )
            ->all ();

    return ArrayHelper::map ( $posts , 'id' , 'first_name' );
}
```

Apart from doing all the above you should get used to of using available resources in form of extensions or plugins that are widely available one of them is [**`Kartik/DepDropdown`**](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop#basic-usage) which does the same thing with a lot of less pain of writing the javascript and just providing data from server-side.

Comment: Wow, Thank you for your detailed reply.
But, it is still not working. I put in exactly the code you provided. The customer dropdown list does not change according to the selected project.

Comment: can you update your question by adding the code you updated ?

Comment: Oh, I found the problem, I was missing  'use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper' in the controller.
Works fine now, thanks a lot Muhammad!!